# ajax didn't call after success another js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax post. I just want to learn how can i call some function after ajax success.

I want to call the following function after ajax success:

```
function col() {
        var $container = $(".post-users-body");
        $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $container.masonry({
                columnWidth: ".collectionPostWrap",
                itemSelector: ".collectionPostWrap"
            });
        });
}
```

The ajax post is this:

```
$("body").on("click","#update_button",function() {
    var updateval = $("#update").val();
    var dataString = 'update=' + updateval ;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "requests/post.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
          $(".post-users-body").prepend(html);
          col();            
        }
      });

    return false;
  });
```

So the ajax post is working fine but it is not calling the `col();` function.

What i am doing wrong here. Anyone can tell me ?

Comment: You can use `console.log(html)` to check again for `html`. Something may be `html` was invalid format, so it couldn't be prepended. Then, `col()` wouldn't be executed.

Comment: @HappyCoding Thank you i have tested your think now and there are everything looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

ajax returns a promise object. use that and do some function chaining.

```
    <script>
        (function(){

            function col(){
                alert("col called");
            }

            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"http://localhost:5850/api/someservice"}
             ).done(function(){
                    debugger;
                    col();
                });
        })()



    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer dear. Can you explain your answer a little bit please ?

Comment: While I know this is an option, I thought JQuery still let you use the success attribute function if that happens to be your preference...

Comment: @KMC i have tested it. same problem here.

Comment: I've updated the code and tested it against my rest service and it works. try debugging using firebug or IE dev toolbar and see if the col function is in scope. Since i dont have all your code, I'm not sure what else I can do.